# Calling jQuery function too many times in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I am committing a single UI action (changing a `select` value), but the corresponding function is being called twice. The function is below.

```
    // doc.js
    $(document).on("change", "select.class", (function(){
        if ($("select.otherSelect").find(":selected").is( ":disabled" ) == false) {
            $.ajax({
                  //Ajax call
            });
            console.log("Selector was changed")
        }
    }));
```

I know the function is being called multiple times because the text "Selector was changed" appears more than once in the JS console when I change the `select` element only once.  Before writing this, changing the `select` element six times in succession caused the function to be called once, then twice, then four times, then eight times, then sixteen times, then thirty-two times.

Why is this?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean!

Comment: I reworded things which should make it easier to read.  Basically, the function I wrote above is being called twice per UI action when I only want it called once.

Comment: You are includiong doc.js more than once in your app.  It's probably being explicitly included in your layout and is also in your asset pipeline

Comment: I don't think so, ilan berci.  I am running this locally so there are no precompile assets (just to be sure, I ran `rake assets:clean`).  I checked the every javascript file loaded by this page and the function is only listed once in any of them.

Comment: Also, before writing this, changing the select element six times in succession caused the function to be called once, then twice, then four times, then eight times, then sixteen times, then thirty-two times.  It isn't simply twice each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue.  To start, I had an entire page whose elements were bound by functions in `$(document).ready(function() {`.  This became problematic because I was using the `select` to asynchronously replace many elements in the page with new elements that needed to be bound by those functions (but weren't, since the binding only happens once).

To get around this, I copied all the content in `$(document).ready(function() {` into a function `docReady()` and then called `docReady()` both inside `$(document).ready(function() {` and whenever I asynchronously reloaded the content of the page.  This strategy caused my error; now I was binding **every** element of the page, including the `select` itself!

Now, I've called the binding functions for the `select` only once in `$(document).ready(function() {` and I call the binding functions for the asynchronously generated elements once every time `select` changes its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "select.class", (function(){
if($(this).data('clicked')) {
      return;
  }
        if ($("select.otherSelect").find(":selected").is( ":disabled" ) == false) {
            $.ajax({
                  //Ajax call
            });
            console.log("Selector was changed")
        }
$(this).data('clicked', true);
    }); //removed here was extra )
```

Comment: This would only allow me to call the function once ever; I need it to be called once every time I change the `select`.  Moreover, the extra `)` belonged there.  If you check http://jsfiddle.net/bb4bk/ you'll see that the `(` after `.on` is unmatched in your solution.  Click immediately after that `(` and it will turn red.  Every other `(` and `)` is matched and will turn green.